# SLURM setting nodes to drain due to low socket-core-thread-cpu count

Tags: linux, slurm

I have SLURM set up with a couple of workstations. There are different kinds, but let's take one with a CPU which has 4 cores and no additional SMT, so 4 threads in total. `lscpu` shows me the following:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               60
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Stepping:            3
CPU MHz:             3478.500
CPU max MHz:         3700.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6584.83
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

Since they are workstations and I am just farming resources, I told SLURM that they only had 2 CPU cores such that it would not schedule more than two single CPU jobs per workstation. But now I need to farm more, so I am pushing for three jobs per workstation. So I told SLURM that they in fact have three cores. But then SLURM set them into the *drain* state:

```
$ scontrol show node=deino
NodeName=deino Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=3 
   CPUAlloc=3 CPUTot=3 CPULoad=4.55
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=deino NodeHostName=deino Version=18.08
   OS=Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u2 (2019-08-08) 
   RealMemory=13000 AllocMem=1500 FreeMem=1299 Sockets=1 Boards=1
   State=ALLOCATED+DRAIN ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=60347 Weight=2 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=batch,long-no-guarantee 
   BootTime=2019-08-23T14:50:20 SlurmdStartTime=2019-08-23T14:51:06
   CfgTRES=cpu=3,mem=13000M,billing=3
   AllocTRES=cpu=3,mem=1500M
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
   Reason=Low socket*core*thread count, Low CPUs [slurm@2019-11-14T13:51:07]
```

I do not understand. I have `CPUs=3 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=3 ThreadsPerCore=1`, so this is less than the machine actually has. I can manually set these nodes to resume, but it feels strange. What do I need to change to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you restart slurmd on all nodes after modifying the cluster definition?
2. On our system we fully declare all resources on each node but use core and memory specialisation to reserve cores / memory for the OS / interactive users. https://slurm.schedmd.com/core_spec.html

Comment: Restarting the `slurmd` process has helped with this. Thanks!